# WPF UserControl - determine start and end of rendering

Tags: wpf, rendering

Is there a way to determine the start and the end of the rendering of a UserControl? I know there is a Windows.ContentRendered event and also this hack:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, new Action(() =>
{
    // do something here
}));
```

But I need to know for the UserControl how long the rendering took, not for the entire Window.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4255664/1979354 and also article from this question is very good - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11611724/1979354

Comment: Hi Spawn, thanks for the hints, this was what I was looking for